# Angular NPM package versioning?

Tags: angular, npm

I'm working on an old npm internal package, we have 2 dependencies that are also internal as you can see from the change shown below, there has been quite a bit of work in these packages, since this was updated.

My question is, is this considered a breaking change? and hence what should I put the version number to 1.0.0 or should we just increment the existing version to 0.0.5 as shown below?

[image]

I have not worked very much with angular npm packages and versions. I know that if I make a breaking code change then I would increase the major version.

If another internal package uses the older packages would this cause a conflict in the project that uses them both if I don't increase the major version?

Comment: As per npm, versioning startpoing is `1.0.0`, any version before `1.0.0` will be considered unstable and `caret` rules will not be applied, well not that it wont be applied but different rules will be applied. If  caret is placed on `0.1.61`, this means that npm update will only let you update patch version, like `tilde` .  This places you in a situation where you can't make a minor update to package which would increment second number of version. Well you can but it will not be installed when running npm update. You have to increase `major` number for stuff to work properly

Comment: Thanks @tony Looks like we need some work, still unsure about the peerDependencies and if I should change major or minor but suppose it depends on if we use a ^ or a ~ for the versions in the projects that use this!